# Non-passive waiting on a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Is it possible for a thread to do some operations before being Waited , what I want to do is that I want this thread to `wait()` another thread before being waited itself,

It's a distributed system with Clients, a Transaction Manager, and a Lock Manager which the last two reside on a middleware server.  The Lock Manager may `wait()` a thread of Transaction Manager, I want this thread to be able to `wait()` Client thread before being waited itself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  `Object.wait()` is final and cannot be overridden.  I'm not actually sure what you mean by a thread being "waited".  You don't call `wait()` on a thread.

Comment: I know that it's final and I can not override it , I wanted to know if it is possible to being somehow informed that someone is making the thread to `Wait`, because the object which is making the thread1 to `wait` is not open source , and I want to make thread2 to `wait` before thread1 being `Waited`.

Comment: I don't understand.  One thread cannot make another thread wait.  Is it calling `Thread.suspend()` or something gross?

Comment: Thanks , I confused for a moment , there's only one thread running the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "wait" another thread. If you call [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) on an object, all it does is sending the current thread to sleep until it is notified (by [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) or [`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)) or due to a so called spurious wake-up. I would recommend reading the ["Lesson: Concurrency" from the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Especially the part about [guarded blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) should be of interest to you.

So, if you want to tell some other thread that you are about to start waiting on an object, for example like this

```
// We are somewhere, in some method ...
synchronized(someObj) {
    someObj.wait();
}
```

you have to implement some kind of observer pattern, where other objects can be registered.

Comment: I know that it's final and I can not override it , what I meant is that if it is possible to being somehow informed that someone is making the thread to Wait,

Comment: You cannot make a thread wait from somewhere else than the thread itself. "Someone" cannot tell a thread to wait. If you want to know that a thread starts to wait on an object, you would have to implement observer pattern yourself and call every observer just before you call wait().